# Propertied Interest

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I'm reading the book *Paris, Capital of Modernity* by David Harvey, in which there is a chapter called "Rent and the Propertied Interest".

Many times, the author uses the term *propertied interest* as if it were some sort of entity. Can this be translated into "the interests of the proprietors", or is it something different that I'm not quite understanding? Here are some examples taken from the book:

> "Daumier frequently criticized landlords and the **propertied interest**"
>
> "Gaillard suggests, the “progressive” large-scale **propertied interests** were Right Bank rather than Left Bank, central rather than peripheral."
>
> "In Paris, the urban-based **propertied interests** constituted a powerful political force
>   under the July Monarchy"
>
> "Much weakened, therefore, the **propertied interest** was willing to accept
>   almost anything that would guarantee the perpetuation of its rights and a resurgence of
>   the market."
>
> "Yet Haussmann’s relations with the **propertied interest** were often troubled and at best ambivalent"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used in this way ***the propertied interest*** means ***the interests of the people who own property***. For this purpose it would mean ***landed property***, i.e. ownership of land and buildings.

***Propertied interest*** is a well-understood, and everyday idiom, particularly among historians, social and political scientists etc.

Some, especially those subscribing to a Marxist theory of history and society, talk of a ***propertied class***.

Comment: I'd push back a little on "everyday idiom"; I'd call it *easily decipherable jargon*. No layman would ever use this in conversation; they'd say "property owners" or "landholders" or any of several  other idioms first.

Comment: Well perhaps not every single day. But in Britain I would expect almost anyone to know what 'propertied interests' meant. It is not something that would, with most people, require 'deciphering'.

Comment: Well, since I'm a foreigner and I am not acquainted with this expression, I just wanted to make sure I got the meaning right.

Comment: @MariaM. If you are a non-native speaker of English, you are excused!

Comment: From the examples given, I understood what it meant (or at least, I reached an understanding—more or less the same as yours—that made sense in the context). But like @Ernest, I would consider “well-understood, and everyday idiom” to be somewhat of an exaggeration. I have never heard it before in my life, and it _did_ take quite a bit of deciphering for me, since it’s not being used in a way entirely comparable to _the interests of property owners_. You would never say, for example that the _interests of_ anyone were willing to accept anything—the people would do that, not their interests.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *Propertied*, as an adjective, is well covered in both the OED and in the dictionary on my Kindle (Oxford Dictionaries on line). adj. *(of a person or group) owning property and land, especially in large amounts: a propertied country gentleman*. Maybe this is an age thing. After all I still talk about *The Ukraine*, and call rice pudding *Burmah Road* just like the old sweats did.  Have you heard of the *moneyed class*, and *landed interests*?

Comment: It’s not _propertied_ that makes this a difficult term to understand to someone who doesn’t know it; it’s _interest_. Your _propertied country gentleman_ is straightforward and simple, but _interest_ in the sense “a group or organization having a common concern, especially in politics or business” ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/interest)) is, in my experience, exceedingly rare, especially in the singular. It basically means almost the opposite of the normal meaning of _interest_: the person having an interest, rather than the interest said person has.

Comment: (More precisely: exceedingly rare at least in non-technical usages. I can’t speak for historians and social/political scientists, because I try to avoid their fields as much as possible. It may well be in common usage within those fields, but I’d almost wager good money that it’s rare outside them.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I just asked my wife, whose first language is Chinese, but who admittedly speaks better English than I do, and she immediately recognised the term *propertied interests*. But she is a psychotherapist. Perhaps you hold the same prejudices against them that you do as regards historians, as well as social and political scientists.

Comment: Can’t say that I do—my lack of exposure to that field is purely coincidental. I’m not all that surprised that she recognised the term; I’m sure lots of people do. My point was that it’s not a _common_ term, and that it’s not a particularly easy term decipher, even to a native speaker, if you are not familiar with it already.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm also a bit puzzled by your saying that it is not *propertied* that is the problem. I'm astonished that a man of your calibre does not know what the abstract noun *interests* means and/or has difficulty combining it with the adjective *propertied*.

Comment: The ‘default’ use of the word _interest(s)_ (in this type of context) is “a stake or involvement in an undertaking” (ODO again), as in “I have no personal interest in this”. That meaning is exceedingly common. It’s the ‘other’ meaning that is, in my experience at least, rare enough to require some deciphering, rather than presenting itself as immediately understandable. “I am an interest in this” just isn’t that common, and this usage would almost certainly cause me to pause and have to decipher before understanding.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not sure what you mean by *I am an interest*. An 'interest' as employed here, is the same interest as in the sentence  *I have an interest* e.g. money invested in something.

Comment: No, it’s not—that’s the whole crux of the matter. An _interest_ as employed here refers to a person, not to an abstract concept; it is more or less a synonym of _stakeholder_ or _interested party_. A _propertied interest_ is a stakeholder who holds or owns property; it is not the property interest that the interest (!) holds. That is what makes things like “the urban-based propertied interests constituted a powerful political force” possible: the people who owned property were a political force, not the stakes/interests they held. It is this sense of _interest_ that is uncommon and technical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not sure I entirely follow you, but would the same sort of problem exist in grasping a concept like *religious interests*, if I said something like *some religious interests are opposed to three-parent births*?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Due to the commonness of _religious_ in comparison to _propertied_, deciphering _religious interests_ in this sense will probably be a good deal easier and quicker than _propertied interests_; but to someone, even a native speaker, who hasn’t come across the term before, neither is immediately obvious and much be deciphered ‘manually’, as it were.

Comment: but why using interests after all? what's the point of having it?

Comment: @MariaM.  Do you know the two quite different meanings of the word *interest*? Take a look in a good dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that "interest" is being used in sense of political power block (though not necessarily one directed at government); a "special interest." [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/special%20interest)

Accordingly, your sense that it means the "interests of the proprietors" is quite correct.

Comment: I concur. I wonder why your answer was downvoted.

Comment: Both the answer and the question were downvoted without comment. Ah, democracy.

Comment: Remember the days of *netiquette*?  :-)

Answer (score 1):

**"Propertied interest" is a legal term and is not interchangeable with "owning" real estate.** It is possible to have an interest in property without actually "owning" the real property. For example, it used to be quite common for a man to leave property to his surviving wife but on her death the land would be owned by the man's son. If the man dies and the wife is alive, the son does not yet own the real property, but the son does have an *interest in the property*, and that interest is strongly protected by law.

Especially in England, where land title can go back more than one thousand years, interests in property can be exceptionally complex. Therefore, if a writer wants to be precise and inclusive, a term such as "propertied interest" is superior to "land owners".

Another illustration that may help: in modern China, all land is owned by the state. People can have 70-year leases on some land, however, and leaseholders are able to sell their leases. A person holding the 70-year lease has almost every [right, duty, power, privilege, and immunity](http://www.hunterthinks.com/opinion/a-hohfeldian-primer) that a full "owner" has in England, but the Chinese leaseholder does not own the land. "Propertied interest" would cover both the Chinese leaseholder and the English land owner, though.

Comment: So "interest" means that you have the right to it? What I find funny is that the author uses "propertied interests" as if it were an entity. From what I undrstood this could be translated into "people who the right to land". Is it what you meant? I just wanted a simply translation for somebody who is a layman, like me.

Comment: I purposely put "own" in quotes because in law, ownership of real property is possibly the most complex area of Anglo-American law. Ownership is often well described as a "bundle of rights [and privileges]" instead of being a binary state: you either own something or you do not own it. An interest in real property can take many forms. I described a future interest, above. It can also be a right to cross the land, to drill for oil, to sublease the land, or many other things. So, yes, "interest" basically means that a person has some sort of right, power, or privilege related to the land.

Comment: I don't disagree with anything you say here, neither in your answer, nor in the comment which follows. However, I do not believe it is in this very detailed understanding of 'an interest in property' that the term *propertied interest* is used by the author of the book that the OP is reading. *Propertied interests* is a term used in the same way as , say, 'religious interests', or 'political interests' to mean those entities out there who have an interest ( a stake) in property.

Comment: That could certainly be true. "When you are good with a hammer, everything is a nail." It is possible that my legal training (the hammer) is causing me to see "propertied interests" as a nail, when it is merely a phrase in the lay vernacular. On the other hand, I do not recall reading "propertied interests" outside of a legal context, but that could be explained by differences in American and British English.